# my old co-workers are all here

Tags: meaning, ambiguit

a. My old co-workers are all here but the new ones aren't.

Isn't that sentence ambiguous?

1. Those people who have been my co-workers for a long time are here, but those who have been my co-workers for a short time aren't.
2. The people who were my co-workers before are all here, but the people who are my co-workers now aren't.

Many thanks

Comment: Before I got to your options, I thought it would be the second meaning.

Answer (score 2):

"Old co-worker" usually means co-workers from a previous job. It does not usually mean people who have been co-workers for a long time. This is different from "old friend", which usually does mean someone who has been a friend for a long time. This is presumably because people rarely make a complete change to their friends, but frequently change their co-workers.

Your option 1 is so rare that it means the sentence is not really ambiguous, and will always be understood to mean option 2.

Comment: Thank you both very much. How would you say (1) in a neater way?

Comment: "My long-term colleagues are all here, but the more recent/newer ones aren't."